# Word for someone who makes fun of others for a characteristic while himself or herself has it

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What is called a person who makes fun of others for a characteristic while himself or herself has it.

For example a short person who scorn someone for being short.

Comment: "The pot calling the kettle black."  Maybe you can make a single word from that well-known expression.

Comment: Urban Dictionary has an entry for [_hater hater_](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hater+hater&defid=1849900), a term that, on its face, would seem to reflect the paradox at work here; but unfortunately the guy who submitted the term attached a lame definition to it, thereby wasting its ironic possibilities.Which I guess makes me a _hater hater_ hater.

Comment: There was a good cartoon some years ago, where a wind-up toy is doubled over in uncontrolled derisive laughter, pointing at a marionette.

Comment: *self-loathing*?  I like *blinkered* for this, but the usual connotation's different than the literal origin which I think makes it apt.

Comment: @GEdgar, You can post your comment as the answer. It seems to be the correct one. We've a expression similar to your comment in Farsi that fit the situation of pointed out in OP.

Answer (score 3):

**hypocrite**
noun  uk    us    /ˈhɪp.ə.krɪt/ disapproving

someone who says they have particular moral beliefs but behaves in way that shows these are not sincere:

He's a hypocrite - he's always lecturing other people on the environment but he drives around in a huge car.

[Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/hypocrite)

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for. My example and yours don't share same idea.

Comment: Yeah,  the two examples **do** include hypocrisy. @Chasly from uk just provided an incomplete definition.

Comment: @Yeshe, Comparing with GEdgar's comment, this is not seem to be the answer.

Comment: The OP has provided an example of hypocrisy and claimed it wasn't. There is no explanation how this isn't hypocrisy, no other examples, no elaboration on what they are seeking. In the absence of anything to the contrary the word for this is **hypocrite**, whether they want to admit it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Derivations from [Pot calling the kettle black] and [Psychological projection] are truly relevant, 'hypocrite' not so much. The person mocking others for traits he has himself is unaware, self-unaware. The double standard of the hypocrite implies conscious purpose. The simple mockerer (is that a word?) is kind of innocent due to unawareness, a hypocrite is not an innocent.

Comment: There's nothing in the question to suggest that the speaker is unaware of their own traits. In the given example of a short person who scorns someone for being short, it would be difficult for the speaker not to be aware of their own stature.

Answer (score 0):

The adjective **self-hating** is often used this way, usually in conjunction with the name of an ethnic or demographic group, so you could say **self-hating short person**. The noun form, **self-hater**, is less common.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like *psychological projection*.

Here's a single-word dictionary definition:

> **Projection**
>   6b :  the attribution of one's own ideas, feelings, or attitudes to other people or to objects
>   [- M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/projection)

And here's a description in more depth:

> Psychological projection, also known as blame shifting, is a theory in psychology in which humans defend themselves against their own unpleasant impulses by denying their existence while attributing them to others. For example, a person who is rude may constantly accuse other people of being rude.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_projection)